# Jquery load logos after select option triggered

Tags: jquery, html, image, performance

I have a form in which at the bottom of it is a `select` logo drop down option. The options in the select are set from folders in the root directory using this piece of code.

> $dirs = glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

These directorys hold logos:

Example: Tires: All tire company logos, Brakes: all brake company logos and so on.

the drop down is similar to this idea but instead of red, blue, green, it loads logos -> [jsfiddle.net/FvMYz](http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz)

after which, based on the selection by the user, the images load from those folders as the person selects different options in the select logo option menu.

My question is, at this point i have over 400 logos, and it my turn into 1000 soon enough, There is a delay when the page loads because of the number of images loading as the client clicks on the form page.

I've heard of the lazy load plugin, but i'm not sure if that method would be intended for this situation, anyone got any advice how to handle this or a point in the right direction on how to solve this loading lag problem?

edit: Sorry, i'm trying to explain it the best i can. ok, The page loads, and no images are loaded. As they fill out the form and get to the logo drop down select options, and select Tires, it loads the tires logos, i don't want those logos to load until they actually select that option. this will avoid having all 400+ images load at once until the client gets on the page.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do you want to delay the images from loading until the whole page has loaded and load the images in the background, sort of hiding that delay from the user?

Comment: Sorry, i'm trying to explain it the best i can. ok, The page loads, and no images are loaded. As they fill out the form and get to the logo drop down select options, and select Tires, it loads the tires logos, i don't want those logos to load until they actually select that option. this will avoid having all 400+ images load at once until the client gets on the page. makes sense?

Comment: the drop down is similar to this idea but instead of red, blue, green, it loads logos -> http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/

Comment: Ah, therein lies the rub. Well you're going to have to dynamically add the options to the list. The best idea I can come up with is to create a JS Object or something that stores the filenames of the images in a particular structure. When the user selects something (capture the event through jQuery), add a bunch of `option` elements to the dropdown with the images from that subset in the object. I can provide a short example in the answer section if you'd like.

Comment: i'm sorry, i dont fully understand what you're talking about, if you can show me an example in an answer form that would be cool.

Answer (score 0):

Following the discussion in the comments section, here is a short example of what I was explaining: http://jsfiddle.net/Sky9C/1/

Here's what I was talking about when I said "JS Object in a particular structure":

```
var filenames = {
    "tires": {
        "big": ["company1.jpg", "company2.jpg"]
    },
    "brakes": {
        "high_quality": ["company3.jpg", "company4.jpg"],
        "low_quality": ["company5.jpg", "company6.jpg"]
    }
};
```

The jQuery that makes it all happen is in the Fiddle. Let me know if you need more clarification, but this is just the concept of what I would do.

Comment: The logos/image that are loaded into the DIV after being selected load based on the detection of whats in the folder using this code: `while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) { //Read images 
     if ($entry != '.' && $entry != '..'){
      $diritems[$x][] = $entry; //Inserts into array
     }
       }`

Comment: So this is not going to work, and I'm sorry, but creating a listing for 400+ logos and then having to update it every time i add a new logo is not possible.

Comment: Well you don't have to keep a manual list of filenames, that was just an example. You can build out the structure in PHP and JSON encode it to be a JSON object you can work with in jQuery. Your choice, though. You can always use the Lazy Load plugin if you'd like. That might suit your needs if you don't feel comfortable writing your own "lazy loader".